GNOME Lock Screen From Command Line/Bash Script
I'm attempting to make a new top bar for my system (Pop OS 22.04) using polybar. I have it all mostly working, and am attempting to make a power menu. I have the logout, power and restart buttons all working, but am struggling on the lock button.
I have a label with the left-click action set a bash script. I have confirmed that the script is getting executed as if I have script launch Firefox it does. The problem is that that I have not been able to find a working command. I have tried
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
xdg-screensaver lock
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver/org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
They all work when run in the terminal, but not in a bash script. I think it may have somthing to do with polybar running them as root, so I tried running them as my user, but that did not solve it.
Is there some command that locks the screen of a specified user/desktop environment?
Thanks. Just comment if any more info is needed.
All of the commands mentioned where taken from answers from this question.

Could you try setting the display in the script? i.e. export DISPLAY=:0 && xdg-screensaver lock

Or some rough logic if the display is not using main default: export DISPLAY=${DISPLAY:-:0} && xdg-screensaver lock

Sure, I won't be able to check for a couple hours though.

I refused to believe this was only available through screensaver controls: loginctl lock-session.

I finally got some time to sit down and test this and have confirmed that it works. I would call it a "forceful" lock, as it skips the animation and blacks the screen. But it still works for what I need. I had no idea loginctl existed. Thank you!

I didn't know about it, either. Looking for ways to solve the issue I learned something new!
So thank you, too! Glad it is working.
